# Is there a way to create a HIT, but delay its availability to Mechanical Turkers?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

Basically, I want to [create a HIT](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_CreateHITOperation.html), but I don't want it to be available to Turkers until after I can retrieve the `HITId` from the new HIT and perform some other business logic.

I don't see a straightforward way to do this from the Amazon docs. One workaround that looks possible is to use the [UpdateHITReviewStatus](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_UpdateHITReviewStatusOperation.html) operation to set the `HITReviewStatus` to `Reviewing` when I don't want it to be viewable, and to `Reviewable` when I want it to be viewable.

Unfortunately I don't see a way to set a custom `HITReviewStatus` upon HIT creation; only a way to set and revert this property after the HIT has already been created (which might be too late). I would like to create a HIT somehow like this (using [RTurk](https://github.com/ryantate/rturk) for Ruby):

```rb
RTurk::Hit.create(title: title) do |hit|
  hit.assignments = assignments
  hit.description = description
  # ... more settings...
  hit.review_status = 'Reviewing'
end
```

This does not work though - I get:

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `review_status=' for #<RTurk::CreateHIT:0x007fb7e5db28c0>
```

However even if this worked, it does seem like an inelegant hack.

Has anyone had success creating a HIT which has intentionally delayed availability or reviewability for Turkers?

Edit: wording

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**: I have never used this library and literally have no idea what it is even for but I installed the gem just to see what is going on and it appears you can do this.

```
RTurk::Hit.create(title: title) do |hit|
  hit.assignments = assignments
  hit.description = description
  # ... more settings...
  hit.set_as_reviewing! # <------ NOTICE THIS LINE
end
```

I discovered this by simply going through this basic step:

```
RTurk::Hit.new(title: 'Title').methods.sort - Object.methods
# => [:assignments, :bonus_payments, :details, :disable!, :dispose!,   
#     :expire!, :extend!, :id, :id=, :map_content, :method_missing, 
#     :normalize_nested_params, :set_as_reviewable!, :set_as_reviewing!, 
#     :source, :source=, :url, :xml_to_hash]
```

The Source Location for this method is [`RTurk::Hit#set_as_reviewing!`](https://github.com/ryantate/rturk/blob/master/lib/rturk/adapters/hit.rb#L106) although it lacks documentation.

Additionally if that does not work one could try this:

```
RTurk::Hit.create(title: title) do |hit|
  hit.assignments = assignments
  hit.description = description
  # ... more settings...
end.hit.set_as_reviewing!
```

Although this implementation will suffer the same as your original question the duration should be extraordinarily short as the cycle is basically

```
 Create -- Web Call ------> Received
                                 |
 Response Object <-- Response ----
   |
 Update -- Web Call -------> Received
```

Furthermore one can provide an `auto_approval_delay` (Not sure what this does but it too may help) Docs state:

> The number of seconds after an assignment for the HIT has been submitted, after which the assignment is considered Approved automatically unless the Requester explicitly rejects it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. `.set_as_reviewing!` is on `RTurk::Hit` but it is not available in `RTurk::CreateHIT`, which is what where it would need to be in the `RTurk::Hit.create(title: title) do |hit| ; end` block. And unfortunately `auto_approval_delay` looks like it configures time until automatic approval, not time until the HIT can be accepted.

Comment: @drake yeah I assumed the first wouldn't work after reviewing the source because of the fact  that it requires a HitID which would not be available yet. Seems like a round trip might be the only functional way to go about this

Answer (score 0):

I use the Python API, not the Ruby, but I assume they have the same functionality. Have you tried setting `MaxAssignments=0` when creating the HIT, then later using `create_additional_assignments_for_hit()` once you want to allow workers? I don't know if the function names are the same, and it is possible that creating a HIT with 0 assignments is considered an error, but worth a shot!

Comment: MaxAssignments=0 is indeed an error: An error occurred (ParameterValidationError) when calling the CreateHITWithHITType operation: The value 0 is invalid for MaxAssignments. Valid values range from 1 to 1000000000

Answer (score 0):

The way to do is is by using HIT Types and [UpdateHITTypeOfHIT](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_UpdateHITTypeOfHITOperation.html). The basic pattern is to:

1. Create a HIT Type which is impossible for anyone to retrieve. You can do that by putting mutually exclusive Qualification on it: `Country == US` and `Country != US`.
2. Create another HIT Type without this impossible requirement.
3. Create a HITs in the impossible to reach HIT Type. You'll get a HIT id for each one. Because of the impossible to satisfy locale requirement, no Worker can see them.
4. When you're ready to show the HIT to the world, call `UpdateHITTypeOfHIT` and change it to the visible HIT Type.

I'm not a Ruby guy, but I coded up a [prototype in Python](https://gist.github.com/trenton/e42463581ec406ac67594521fcf99201). Here's the output. Hope this gives you some ideas on how to do it.

```
Hidden HIT Type: 3UL1O09SX9IFON31CFQVVXR348R90N
Visible HIT Type: 3DIFNAQ3LCEUPUBCT8DVOVQM1RE3TC

Created HIT 3PZDSVZ3J4GXNMGD2YQL4LJ9SQHN40 of type 3UL1O09SX9IFON31CFQVVXR348R90N

Changed HIT 3PZDSVZ3J4GXNMGD2YQL4LJ9SQHN40 to type type 3DIFNAQ3LCEUPUBCT8DVOVQM1RE3TC

You can now see it here:

https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/preview?groupId=3DIFNAQ3LCEUPUBCT8DVOVQM1RE3TC
```